# SQL Server "linevals" keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm doing small exercise on Northwind DB:

```
update orders set totalvalue = (select sum(odvalue)
from
(select price*quantity as odvalue
from [order details] od join pricelist pl on od.productid=pl.productid
where od.orderid=orders.orderid and orderdate<date_to and
orderdate>=date_from) linevals)
```

What is the meaning of "linevals"? (without this keyword there is an error). 
Google says nothing.

Comment: It is an Alias for the Select query that begins `(select price*quantity as odvalue...`, in SQL Server all derived tables require an explicit alias. This ambiguity is why I try (not always successfully to introduce all aliases with `AS` even though it is not required.

Answer (score 4):

`linevals` is the [alias](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455.aspx) of the [derived table](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1042/using-derived-tables-to-simplify-the-sql-server-query-process/) formed by the query `(select price*quantity...date_from)`.

This could arguably be written more explicitly this way: `as linevals`

Answer (score 1):

It is an Alias for the inner query , which is required by syntax,

Whenever you have a sub-query in your from clause it must have an alias something like

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   ( SELECT * FROM TABLEA) A --<-- This A is the alias for this sub-query
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original query, `linevals` is called an alias.  In this case, it is a table/subquery alias because it is the name of the subquery.  That way, SQL Server can recognize which columns come from which tables.

In general, it is a good idea to use table abbreviations for table aliases -- that is, short names that make sense.  I notice you already follow this best practice.

You don't need the subquery.  Here is a version that is easier to read:

```
update orders o
    set totalvalue = (select sum(price*quantity) as odvalue
                      from [order details] od join
                           pricelist pl
                           on od.productid = pl.productid
                      where od.orderid = orders.orderid and
                            orderdate < date_to and
                            orderdate >= date_from
                     );
```

This also has the advantage that it will work in more databases.  Oracle and MySQL, for instance, do not allow a correlated condition inside a nested subquery.

Comment: SQL server doesn't allow alliasing in updating:                   update orders o set totalvalue=1 where 1=1                           is not ok, while without the alias 'o' query is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Its the name of the inner query.

It doesn't need to be any specific word. I normally write

```
as x
```

after my sub query